# ADFS WIA - как получить доступ к доменному сайту CRM?

Tags: python, windows, crm

Нужно написать скрипт, который бы мониторил состояние сайта - ожидаемый код ответа 200. Сайт доменный, у меня есть логин, пароль, домен и зарегистрированный клиент (и его ID).
Вопрос не в коде, а скорее в механизме.
Вводные:

1. Начальный сайт- https://some_site.domain.ru/  (CRM , версия - 2016 onpremise)
2. Идет редирект на https://some_site.domain.ru/adfs/ls/wia?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=....
3. После ввода логина и пароля - перенаправление на нужный сайт.

Вопрос - что нужно для того, чтобы сделать это скриптом? Токен? Как его получить, если здесь не /adfs/oauth2/authorize. а именно WIA? Пока ловлю только 401 ошибку.

Очень нужно понять, как это работает.

Comment: *Нужно написать скрипт, который бы мониторил состояние сайта* — Зачем вам логин пароль, если до авторизации понятно, что сайт работает?

Comment: нужно проверить именно доступность сайта после авторизации

Comment: По авторизациям полно [вопросов-ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Brequests%5D+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5). Что касается Oauth2, авторизация откуда? Если какая-нибудь соц. сеть, то достаточно авторизоваться там в сессии, потом использовать Oauth2, с корпоративными порталами примерно та же история, но на примере разобрать сферического коня гораздо сложнее.

Comment: Усложняется оно ещё и тем, что авторизация может быть через сертификаты